# Why doesn't this to_date work, when the results have been filtered to match my date format (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table 'A' with one column (VARCHAR2). The table contains a row containing the text '01/01/2021' and another row with the text 'A'.

When I try to filter out 'A' and then to_date the remaining value, I get 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'. I've tried this in 2 ways.

```
select *
from tbl
where col <> 'A'
and to_Date(col,'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_date('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY');

select *
from (  select * 
        from tbl 
        where col <> 'A')
where to_Date(col,'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_date('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

I can understand why the first might not work, but in the second example, the to_date should ONLY ever see filtered data (i.e. '01/01/2020').

When I delete the value of 'A', the statement runs and I get my result back so it seems conclusive that the reason it isn't running is because it's trying to to_date the value of 'A', even though that should have been filtered out by then.

I have been able to replicate this using actual Oracle tables but unfortunately when I try and reproduce the tables using WITH AS, the query works and no error is encountered - another mystery!

Why doesn't this query work? The order of operation seems to be satisfied (and it works if I use WITH AS).

Comment: Oracle doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation of `where` conditions.  That said, I thought that Oracle didn't generate an error unless the row was returned in the result set.  I find it hard to reproduce the error:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b79b75cbb60b3375092d0bcef3fbfdbc.

Comment: Why are you storing dates in `varchar` column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Unless something has changed recently(ish), Oracle can generate an error even if the row is filtered out subsequently.  There was a really good discussion a while ago where Chris Date and a bunch of really smart folks discussed the issue.  Unfortunately, most of the original articles are no longer online but at least an email thread has been archived https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Re2-A-Cure-for-Madness,3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's a 'temporary' table that is used for quick data comparisons. I tend to import data from spreadsheets for quick data comparisons and in this instance I knew of all the values that weren't dates so I thought I could quickly filter them out here, rather than in the spreadsheet itself. No data is stored like this for business use. Only in these temporary 'comparison' tables.

Comment: @JustinCave . . . Interesting.  What seems like a regular occurrence in SQL Server rarely happens in Oracle (in my experience).  I thought Oracle had more conscious optimizations to avoid it.  I suppose that it simply doesn't push predicates to (the equivalent of) the scan node, which is the most common cause of this problem in SQL Server.  By the way, I consider it a bug.  Errors on rows not returned to the user should not return an error, if you are thinking set-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle (and other databases) are under no obligation to evaluate the predicate applied to an inline view before evaluating the outer predicate.  Frequently, in fact, from a performance optimization standpoint, you want the optimizer to push a selective predicate from an outer query into a view, inline view, or subquery.  In this case, whether the query throws an error will depend on the query plan the optimizer chooses and which predicate it actually evaluates first.

As a quick hack, you can change the inline view to prevent predicates from being pushed.  In this case, the presence of a `rownum` stops the optimizer from pushing the predicate.  You could also use hints like `no_push_pred` to try to force the optimizer to use the plan you want

```
select *
from (  select t.*, rownum rn
        from tbl t
        where col <> 'A')
where to_Date(col,'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_date('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

The issue with either of these quick hacks, though, is that some future version of the optimizer might have more options than you are aware of today so you may have problems in the future.

A better option is to rewrite the query such that you don't care what order the predicates are evaluated.  In this case (depending on Oracle version), that's pretty easy since `to_date` allows you to specify a value when there is a conversion error

```
select *
from tbl
where col <> 'A'
and to_Date(col default null on conversion error,'DD/MM/YYYY') = 
      to_date('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

If you're on an earlier version of Oracle or `to_date` is just an example of the actual problem, you can create a custom function that does the same thing.

```
create function safe_to_date( p_str in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 )
  return date
is
begin
  return to_date( p_str, p_fmt );
exception
  when value_error
  then
    return null;
end safe_to_date;
select *
from tbl
where col <> 'A'
and safe_to_date(col,'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_date('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY');
```